# Universal image Loader : Open actual size image on click of an imageview inside listview

Tags: android, image, listview, universal-image-loader

I am using **Universal  image Loader** to bind images to `ImageView` inside my `listview`. These images are being fetched from online url at time of binding asynchronously. Now i want to open the actual size image on click of `ImageView`. Do i have to cache the images when binding or can i use `imageView` source to call intent that will handle displaying the Image.
I have the below code that opens any image on the device :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + yourfilepath);
intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

In what way i can simply display the image loaded using **Universal  image Loader** in user's default image viewer app on click event of `listview`.

Comment: If you uses DisplayImageOptions of the universal image loader, your images will be cached. So that you can use the url of the image to load by using displayimage of the universal loader

imageLoader.displayImage(your_url, your_imageview,
    your_options);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use DisplayImageOptions of the universal image loader, your images will be cached. So that you can use the url of the image to load by using displayimage of the universal loader

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
DisplayImageOptions options;
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.img_default)
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.img_default)
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.img_default).cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true).considerExifParams(true).build();
imageLoader.displayImage(your_url, your_imageview, options);
```

You use your own activity with an image view to show the image. You can send the url through extras and load the url in the image view using displaymage().

Comment: If my images are being cached then can't I get access to the cached image's local path and then fire intent that can display the image from local path ? Because i prefer to display full image through user's Gallery app or any other default app.

Comment: You can do so.. But using url is a simple one. But its quite difficult with default apps.

Comment: Ok so using Url if i display image in new Activity using **imageLoader.displayImage** then it will fetch image from url or from local cache ?